# Proof of an integral property

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1  f(x)g'(x)dx=\pi$$ If $f(1)g(1)=f(0)g(0)$ then $$\int_0^1 f'(x)g(x)dx= -\pi$$
So I have to prove this and I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I am guessing I will have to use the fundamental theorem of calculus and it show that the rate of change is $1$ because it didn't change from  $f(1)g(1)$ to  $f(0)g(0)$

Comment: Do you know [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Utilize [integration by parts](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx):

$$\int f(x)g'(x)\mathrm dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f'(x)g(x) \mathrm dx$$

If we have a definite integral, then this formula becomes

$$\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\mathrm dx = f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a) - \int_a^b f'(x)g(x) \mathrm dx$$

Comment: thank you so much for the answer  ∫baf(x)g′(x)dx=−∫baf′(x)g(x)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{d(f(x)\cdot g(x))}{dx}=?$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$ between $[0,1]$